# Determine whether the integral converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine whether the following integral converges or diverges: \begin{align*} \iint_Q e^{-xy} \ dA, \end{align*} where $Q$ is the first quadrant of the $xy$-plane.

How should I go about this problem? Should I compare it with another known integral?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the integral $I$ to polar coordinates.  Then $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho^2 \sin\phi \cos\phi}\rho d\rho d\phi$$The inner (improper Riemann integral) is trivial.  The polar integral that remains is $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \csc(2\phi)  d\phi=\frac12 \int_0^{\pi} \csc(\phi)  d\phi$$which has singularities at both the upper and lower limits.  Proceeding in the spirit of a Cauchy Principal value $$I=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \log\left[ \frac{\csc(\pi-\epsilon)+\cot(\pi-\epsilon)}{\csc(\epsilon)+\cot(\epsilon)} \right]$$This limit does not exist!

Comment: Dr. MV, well done! +1.

Comment: Olivier Oloa, Thanks!  Coming from you, that is a big compliment.  I did take the liberty of interchanging the limit for the radial integral with the angular integral without applying rigor.

Answer (score 1):

A  comparison with the area under a branch of a hyperbola does the trick,$$
\iint_Qe^{-xy}dxdy \geq e^{-1}\iint_Q1_{xy \leq 1}dxdy = e^{-1} \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x}= +\infty.
$$